# Bash+SFTP shell: sort filtered file list?

Tags: bash, shell, sftp

I have a weird problem while interacting with an SFTP server. What I need to do is log in, find the latest file that satisfies certain criteria, and download it. All this from a bash script. The way it was accomplished so far was by simply running `ls -lt` and taking the first line of the output:

```
echo "ls -lt" > tmp.sftp
sftp -b tmp.sftp user@ftps.server.com:/inbox 1>sftp.log 2>&1

FILE=$(cat sftp.log | sed -n 3p |  awk '{print $NF}')

echo "get $FILE" > tmp.sftp
sftp -b tmp.sftp user@ftps.server.com:/inbox
```

However, they have recently started putting other files (that I don't care for) to that same folder. I tried changing the code to do `ls -lt blah*`, but for some reason when there is a wildcard filter, the file list gets sorted in reverse order...

I feel like the way I am solving this is ridiculous, there should be a better way. Which way do I look? Curl? Wget? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the order of the output of your *ls* by adding the *-r* flag.

```
ls -ltr
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can do `sftp`, you can do `ssh` and `scp`. They all use the same daemon process: `sshd`:

This might make your task a wee bit easier than trying to do everything through `scp`.

With `ssh`, you can execute a remote command and have that remote command report back to your system:

```
$ ssh user@ftps.server.com ls -lt inbox
```

This will list the files on the remote system in name order. By the way, why the whole conniption with `-l` in the `ls` command? Why not simply do this:

```
$ ls -t | head -1
```

That will list the latest file for you, and you could do that remotely:

```
$ FILE=$(ssh user@ftps.server.com ls -t inbox | head -1)
```

Once you have that file, you could use `scp` to copy it:

$ scp user@ftps.server.com:/inbox/$FILE .

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately `ssh user@ftps.server.com` hangs, I assume they have users' shells set to `/bin/false` or something.